# Speeding up loading speed

Tags: sql

I have an record keeping app which loads the records in 2 seconds until it went live. Then all the records that were racking up in the database caused the loading time to be 30 seconds or more at least.

According to a back-end developer,  8000-10000 is the max i can store in the db , the rest of the past day records I'd have to manually back-up and delete all previous-day records to let it load faster. Is there any way the search index at the database could be optimized to load faster even with records <= 60-80k?

All files are stored at AWS, and when loading the records it all goes on in the server.

Comment: Wait? Are you loading all records into memory at one time?

Comment: question needs more info and context. You might have an XY problem...

Comment: How many records are you displaying at a time? If you are displaying ten at a time from 10,000 records then you are meant to be using SQL that filters it so that only ten records are sent. Without background and code we are just guessing though. It sounds like you are loading them locally and then filtering them.

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases, adding index could significantly increase query speed.

For example, if each record of your log has a timestamp field, you can create an index on the timestamp column. With the index, when you execute queries such as `select * from logs where timestamp > xxx`, the query will leverage the index to find the records after the given time much faster.